# The image is too small when I try to upload it using Facebook Graph API and Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Simply put I need to capture image using camera and upload it to facebook via my android application. And I successfully did that. The problem is when the photo posted in facebook, it's just too small and in low resolution while the image I took is in high resolution.

I understand that: in order to upload to facebook, i need to convert the captured image which is in bitmap format into byte array. So i have method for that:

```
public static byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bm){
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
        return bitmapdata;
    }
```

Then to upload the image to facebook, i have code below where byteData is byte array I converted from bitmap image using the method above.

```
parameters.putString("message", "Test");
parameters.putByteArray("source", byteData);
String facebookResponse = facebookInstance.request(albumId+"/photos",parameters,"POST");
        return facebookResponse;
```

I am pretty sure the problem is my convertBitmapToByteArray method since the method is to compress the bitmap image and turn it into byte array, and this made my image into low resolution image. However I can't seem to find the way to upload the image without converting it into byte array first. Any solution for me?

Comment: Did you try using compressformat.JPEG? at 100 quality it may solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Alright even this thread is old, i found out the answer. It's not the problem of CompressFormant.JPEG or CompressFormat.JPG. Simply put, intent in android isn't designed to carry big data like image from activity through activity. I need to save the image from intent to sd card first before able to pull it out from there. It's my solution.